# I am try to login with django using Angular4

Tags: django, angular

i create Rest API for login in Django and i want to call it in angular4
heare is my angular4 code

login.components.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Http, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router:Router, private http:Http) { }

  getData = [];
```

**with this function i get data from my API**and i am trying to compare this data with form data

```
  fatchData = function(){
    this.http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/loginAdmin/").subscribe((res:Response) => {
      this.getData = res.json();
    })
  }

  loginUser(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var username = e.target.elements[0].value;
    var password = e.target.elements[1].value;
    if(username == 'this.getData.username' && password == 'this.getData.password')
    {
      this.router.navigate(['/deshbord'])
    }
    else{
      console.log('Error Find');
    }
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.fatchData();
  }

}
```

**this is my login.comonents.login i want that when user give user name and password its compare with my API data and it's true then navigate to other page..**

```
<form (submit)="loginUser($event)">
  <div class="input">
    <label>UserName</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>

  <div class="input">
    <label>password</label>
    <input type="password">
  </div>

  <div class="input">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
  </div>
</form>
```